# How to print output of python script to Windows console, when running via batch file?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, automation

I've been looking for an answer to this backwards and forwards but to no avail. I work on Windows and wrote a script in Python which copies a source files to other backup destinations (Dropbox folder and remote drive).

```
import os, shutil

source = r'C:\****\****\Accounts_Passes.kdbx'
file_name = source.split('\\')[-1]
cloud_backup = r'C:\****\Dropbox\Backup'
pendrive_backup = r'I:'

def backup (source, destination):
    if not os.path.exists(destination):
        os.mkdir(destination)
    shutil.copy(source, destination)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    if os.path.exists(pendrive_backup.split('\\')[0]):
        backup(source, pendrive_backup)
        print(f"{file_name} file backed up to pendrive!")
    else:
        print(f"Pendrive disconnected, couldn't backup {file_name} to it")
    backup(source, cloud_backup)
    print(f"{file_name} file backed up to Dropbox!")
    print("DONE!")
```

I want it to run it via Windows Task Scheduler so I created a .bat file.

```
echo off
echo Backup launched
timeout /t 5
start "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" "C:\*****\Backup Scripts\Keypass_backup.py"
pause
```

The problem is when I run it via .bat file the output of the Python script doesn't show in the console which I would strongly demand. Any advice on how to make the command line opened via batch file, **display the print outputs** of the Python script would be great.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Just a redirect: `> keypass_log.txt` to the end of the `start` line in your batch file. Print it out later.

Comment: Please do not ask questions about issues with scripts run under Windows Task Scheduler, without providing all of the details about the scheduled task.  Things like what was entered into 'Security options', 'Triggers', 'start in', 'Settings/Advanced settings', 'Actions', and 'Conditions'. We need to know under which user account/context the task will be run as and importantly when it will be run. Importantly you should know, if you want to see the task run, i.e. not run hidden, that you must choose `"run only when user is logged in"` from the 'General' tab of the Task Scheduler properties page.

Comment: @quarama - thank you! That  kind of does the trick but still if it was possible to acomplish it without creating additional text files that would be great.

Comment: @Compo - the task scheduler doesn't matter over here. The Task works just fine. I just want the console to return the print statments provided in the Python Scripts.

Comment: @Compo - Thank you very much! Deleting "start" does exactly what I wanted !

Comment: I've deleted the comments @MichaelPeter, and added them as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is that you correct your batch file content.

You should get rid of `start` from line `4` of your provided content.

```batch-file
@Echo Backup launched
@%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak
@"%ProgramFiles%\Python38\python.exe" "C:\*****\Backup Scripts\Keypass_backup.py"
@Pause
```

If you wanted to ignore that advice and use `start` anyhow, then the correct syntax would be:

```batch-file
@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Python38\python.exe" "C:\*****\Backup Scripts\Keypass_backup.py"
```

Without that syntax, your `start` command was actually using `C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe` as a 'Window Title', and running the command, `"C:\*****\Backup Scripts\Keypass_backup.py"`, which isn't what you wanted it to do.

If you open up a Command Prompt window, type either `start /?` or `help start`, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you should see that the first set of doublequotes is for defining the title.

*Also, you should be able to run `"C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe"` via the task scheduler, with `"C:\*****\Backup Scripts\Keypass_backup.py"` as an argument, without the need for a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) at all. You could probably even do that by running `cmd.exe` via the task scheduler, with `/K`, `"C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe"` and `"C:\*****\Backup Scripts\Keypass_backup.py"` as its arguments too.*